# Tikz Payoff Matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-pic

I am trying to remove the bottom two rows (C and D) completely so as to create a 2*4 payoff matrix. In addition to this, I would also like to move "Player 2" up slightly once they have been removed (roughly between A and B). I am having trouble figuring out how to do so and was wondering if anyone could help?

[image]

What I'd like it to look like more or less (with "Player 2" re-positioned to the middle of A and B):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"T","F","G","T"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","C","D"}}

\matrix[matrix of math nodes,draw,
every odd row/.style={align=right},every evenrow/.style={align=left},
nodes={text width=1.5cm},row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm]
          (m) {2&3&6&5\\12&2&9&9\\-1&0&0&2\\0&0&0&3\\2&3&6&1\\4&2&-1&8\\4&2&4&8\\4&2&-1&7\\};
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,2,3}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2,3}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/8}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/8}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}

\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Player 1};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Player 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tried to keep the same code skeleton you provided. The only thing that I might have changed is the two empty entires in `\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","",""}}` (but it gets the job done nicely :)).

### Newer Answer:

[image: Newer Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"T","F","G","T"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","",""}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, 
            draw, every odd row/.style={align=right},
            every evenrow/.style={align=left}, 
            nodes={text width=1.5cm},
            row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm]
          (m) {
            2&3&6&5\\
            12&2&9&9\\
            -1&0&0&2\\
            0&0&0&3\\
            };
% Horizontal line
\draw ({$(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-2-1)!0.5!(m-3-1)$}-|m.east);
% Vertical lines
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1,...,3}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
}

\foreach\x in{0,1,2,3}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/8}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/4}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Player 1};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Player 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

### Previous Answer:

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{natbib}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}\begin{tikzpicture}
\def\myrowhead{{"T","F","G","T"}}
\def\mycolhead{{"A","B","",""}}
\matrix[matrix of math nodes, 
        draw, every odd row/.style={align=right},
        every evenrow/.style={align=left}, 
        nodes={text width=1.5cm},
        row sep=0.2cm,column sep=0.2cm]
        (m){
            2&3&6&5\\
            12&2&9&9\\
            -1&0&0&2\\
            0&0&0&3\\
          };
\foreach\x[count=\xi from 2,evaluate={\xx=int(2*\x);\xxi=int(\xx+1)}] in {1}{
  \draw ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.north) -- ({$(m-1-\x)!0.5!(m-1-\xi)$}|-m.south);
  \draw ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.west) -- ({$(m-\xx-1)!0.5!(m-\xxi-1)$}-|m.east);
}
\foreach\x in{0,1,2,3}{
  \node[text depth=0.25ex,above=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/8}!(m.north east)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\myrowhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
  \node[left=2mm] at ($(m.north west)!{(2*\x+1)/4}!(m.south west)$)
     {\pgfmathparse{\mycolhead[\x]}\pgfmathresult};
}
\node[above=18pt of m.north] (firm b) {Player 1};
\node[left=1.6cm of m.west,align=center,anchor=center] {Player 2};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I am wondering if you can add the missing vertical lines.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have updated my answer. The previous one didn't include all the vertical lines.

Comment: @M.AlJumaily  Thank you! I appreciate your help with this problem.

Answer (score 7):

Just to show you don't need a Ti*k*Z matrix to draw your table, some nested `tabular`s are enough.

For convenience, I used a macro for the couple of payoffs, as in marmot's answer.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\pft}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}C{1em}@{\hspace{1.5em}}C{1em}@{}} \rule{0pt}{3ex} & #1 \\[1ex] #2 & \\[1ex] \end{tabular}} 
\newcommand{\myh}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{C{#1}}{#2}} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{c@{}C{1.5em}|*4{C{4em}}} 
  & \myh{1.5em}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Player 1} \\[1ex] 
  & \myh{1.5em}{} & \myh{4em}{T} & \myh{4em}{F} & \myh{4em}{G} & \myh{4em}{T} \\[1ex] 
  Player 2 & 
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{% 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5em}|*4{C{4em}|}@{}} 
      \cline{2-5} 
      A & \pft{2}{12} & \pft{3}{2} & \pft{6}{9} & \pft{5}{9} \\ 
      \cline{2-5} 
      B & \pft{-1}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{2}{3} \\ 
      \cline{2-5} 
    \end{tabular}} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you like to have "Player 2" rotated, you can use `\rotatebox` from `graphicx` package with the option `origin=c` for a correct alignment:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
\newcommand{\pft}[2]{\begin{tabular}{@{}C{1em}@{\hspace{1.5em}}C{1em}@{}} \rule{0pt}{3ex} & #1 \\[1ex] #2 & \\[1ex] \end{tabular}} 
\newcommand{\myh}[2]{\multicolumn{1}{C{#1}}{#2}} 
\begin{document} 
\begin{center} 
\begin{tabular}{c@{}C{1.5em}|*4{C{4em}}} 
  & \myh{1.5em}{} & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Player 1} \\[1ex] 
  & \myh{1.5em}{} & \myh{4em}{T} & \myh{4em}{F} & \myh{4em}{G} & \myh{4em}{T} \\[1ex] 
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Player 2} & 
  \multicolumn{5}{c}{% 
    \begin{tabular}{@{}C{1.5em}|*4{C{4em}|}@{}} 
      \cline{2-5} 
      A & \pft{2}{12} & \pft{3}{2} & \pft{6}{9} & \pft{5}{9} \\ 
      \cline{2-5} 
      B & \pft{-1}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{2}{3} \\ 
      \cline{2-5} 
    \end{tabular}} 
\end{tabular} 
\end{center} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) A clever solution!

Comment: @CarLaTeX Very interesting. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This answer comes with a style `payoff matrix` which does all the work for you. All you need to do is to say

```
\matrix [payoff matrix]{& T & F & G & T\\
 A & \pft{2}{12}  & \pft{3}{2} & \pft{6}{9} & \pft{5}{9}  \\
 B & \pft{-1}{0}  & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{2}{3}  \\
};
```

where `\pft` takes two arguments, the entry at the top right and bottom left of the cell. The names of the players are stored in pgf keys so that you can change them easily.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{payoff matrix/.style={matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 nodes={/utils/exec=\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1
  \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>1
  \tikzset{
  text height=1.2em,text width=4em,draw}
  \fi
 \fi,
 align=center,anchor=center},
 column 1/.style={text width=1em},
 row 1/.style={text depth=0.3em},
 execute at end matrix={%
 \path (\tikzmatrixname-2-2.west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-2-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.east)
 coordinate[midway] (aux) 
 node[anchor=south,draw=none] at (\tikzmatrixname.north-|aux){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/payoff
 matrix/player 1}};
 \path (\tikzmatrixname-2-2.north) -- 
 (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2.south)
 coordinate[midway] (aux) 
 node[anchor=south,draw=none,rotate=90] at (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.west){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/payoff
 matrix/player 2}};}},
 payoff matrix/.cd,player 1/.initial={Player 1},player 2/.initial={Player 2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\pft}[2]{{\hfill$#1$ \\ $#2$\hfill\mbox{}}}
\matrix [payoff matrix]{& T & F & G & T\\
A & \pft{2}{12}  & \pft{3}{2} & \pft{6}{9} & \pft{5}{9}  \\
B & \pft{-1}{0}  & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{2}{3}  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

And here is why I do believe it makes sense to use Ti*k*Z here: it is straightforward to add some features (and also `Player 2` is rotated and centered without pain). (Of course I agree that if you do not want to have the freedom of adding features, and do not want to rotate `Player 2`, a plain tabular is fine.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\tikzset{payoff matrix/.style={matrix of nodes,column sep=-\pgflinewidth,row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
 nodes={/utils/exec=\ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>1
  \ifnum\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn>1
  \tikzset{
  text height=1.2em,text width=4em,draw,
  path picture={\fill[blue!20] (path picture bounding box.north west) -|
   (path picture bounding box.south east);
  \fill[red!20] (path picture bounding box.north west) |-
   (path picture bounding box.south east);}}
  \fi
 \fi,
 align=center,anchor=center},
 column 1/.style={text width=1em},
 row 1/.style={text depth=0.3em},
 execute at end matrix={%
 \path (\tikzmatrixname-2-2.west) -- (\tikzmatrixname-2-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentcolumn.east)
 coordinate[midway] (aux) 
 node[anchor=south,draw=none,path picture={}] at (\tikzmatrixname.north-|aux){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/payoff
 matrix/player 1}};
 \path (\tikzmatrixname-2-2.north) -- 
 (\tikzmatrixname-\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-2.south)
 coordinate[midway] (aux) 
 node[anchor=south,draw=none,path picture={},rotate=90] at (aux-|\tikzmatrixname.west){\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/payoff
 matrix/player 2}};}},
 payoff matrix/.cd,player 1/.initial={Player 1},player 2/.initial={Player 2}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\newcommand{\pft}[2]{{\hfill$#1$ \\ $#2$\hfill\mbox{}}}
\matrix [payoff matrix]{& T & F & G & T\\
A & \pft{2}{12}  & \pft{3}{2} & \pft{6}{9} & \pft{5}{9}  \\
B & \pft{-1}{0}  & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{0}{0} & \pft{2}{3}  \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is really neat. Thanks for taking the time to share it.